# Coverting a .BAK file into a .SQL for use in XAMPP phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, web, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a .bak file and I need to import it into a database (need a .sql file) using xampp's phpmyadmin (local development). I have only found solutions for Windows SQL server. How can I do this for xampp?

I got the file from a client which means I don't have the access to their server and I can't do a database export.

Comment: Do you need to convert SQL Server Database(.bak file) into MySQL(.sql file)?

Comment: Yes I do, I have tried to import the .bak file but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to follow below steps in order to complete migration from SQL Server Database to MySQL.

1. Restore .bak file on your local SQL Server Instance.
2. You can use MySQL WorkBench's Database Migration tool to convert your backup file to mysql database on your local machine.

   [MySQL WorkBench Tool Database Migration](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/)

3. Once MySQL database is in place, you can dump it into .sql file.

   ```
   $ mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
   ```
4. Finally you can run this sql file on your phpmyadmin interface.

Comment: Will this work if I am using Xampp? All I received is a .bak file from the client and need to use that to set up the database in phpmyadmin so I can edit the site locally.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to execute .sql file in Xampp/phpymyadmin to setup mysql database.

Comment: When I start the SQL Migration, it asked for a source and target RDBMS connection parameters. What would I put in that?

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed on your machine? You would need to restore backup file on your SQL Server and then specify connection string for restored SQL Server database.

Comment: I got xampp installed on my computer (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) - link if you are unfamiliar with xampp, and I was handed a .bak file that I need to convert into a .sql file so that I am able to upload it and use to develop the site locally. I do not have access to the server that has the database on it. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: If I am not mistaken XAMPP is meant PHP development which supports to connection to different databases. You would need to install SQL Server Express edition(https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299) and then restore back file on that server.